# "only if we ignored X, might Y happen"?

Tags: tenses, conditionals

In spite of the general guidance on conditionals found on this site, I am struggling with which tenses to use in the following sentence to properly convey what I mean:

> Only if we ignored these success cases might this seem
>   impossible.

To be clear about my intended meaning, I believe that

- "ignoring these success cases" is a foolhardy thing to do
- "this" is very much possible [therefore, the construction should make "this seem[ing] impossible" adequately remote]

Given this, is there a better combination of verb tenses for me to consider?

Comment: When reading it, it seems like the problem is with the word "only" at the beginning of your sentence. I might reverse the sentence to draw attention to the "only if" part: "The only way this might seem impossible is if we ignored these success cases." Depending on context, I might also replace "this" with the thing that you're actually talking about.

Comment: Please be more specific, but perhaps "It is only by ignoring contrary evidence (*X*), that *Y* seems possible."

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, thank you for this. I like this alternative formulation ("it is only by ignoring X that Y seems impossible") very much. To a native speaker, does it properly convey the two points listed above (namely, that one shouldn't ignore X and that Y isn't impossible at all)?

Comment: @Lara it does to me.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Please answer in an answer box as I would like to vote your suggestion above the current answers.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want a construction like "It is only by ignoring contrary evidence (X), that Y seems possible." For example,

> It is only by ignoring the manifest evidence of the very basic laws of aerodynamics and gravity, that a child believes s/he can fly by simultaneously flapping the arms and jumping off roof.

Answer (score 0):

I would spin it around:

> It would seem impossible, if we were to ignore these success cases

But I agree with commenter 'brandonjsmith' about more specificity

Comment: These successes prove it's not impossible.

Answer (score 0):

The more traditional way to write this would be:

> This might seem impossible only if we ignore these success cases.
>
> This only seems impossible if we ignore these success cases.

In both cases, it should be "ignored" instead of "ignore".

Answer (score 0):

"Only if we ignored these success cases might this seem impossible."

Guessing the context, someone is describing something to a listener who would not believe it is possible.
They are explaining that it is possible if the listener will believe that there is proof, which they claim exists.
It sounds like a sentence from an infomercial, where the host has stories of people that made millions and is describing it to the audience.